# Careers filter workweek hours or fte

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I noticed that the http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ website has no [FTE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full-time_equivalent) filter. I was just browsing for a remote working saturday hobby project.
I think that this filter would be a great addition to the careers 2.0 site.
if you search for it, only two companies popup that say that it is possible to work parttime, but no estimated weekly hours are listed.

Answer (score 4):

After this pilot period, it's clear that the option for employers to mark their listings as full time or contract work is being well utilized!

This is awesome news and we're getting to work on launching a filter for candidates to sort by full time and contract roles. It should be up shortly - I'll post an update then.

Comment: Awesome indeed, cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your followup!

Answer (score 2):

We just recently included an option for employers to mark their listings as full time or contract work.  We're waiting to see how many companies specify this (outside the default) in order to make it a useful filter for job search.

Work hours is a great idea, especially if the employer has chosen contract, and we'll look into it.

Comment: Thanks, that would be awesome. Looking forward to it. Is there an ETA? or is it already live and only visible if companies specify it?

Comment: This is live for companies filling out jobs.  We're waiting to make it a candidate filter until we see how accurately they are using the choice.  We should know in about a month if they're using it right and it would be a useful filter for candidates.

Comment: Any updates, three months later?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Posted below. We're working on this feature now that we had proper time to test that it's working!